# Can you mmap (user) and ioremap_nocache (kernal) the same phys address?

Tags: mmap, ioremap

Can you mmap (user) and ioremap_nocache (kernal) the same phys address say that of an fpga?

Answer (score 0):

yes . mmap will map device address to user space  and ioremap will map device address to kernel virtual address. Both return addresses will point to same  device address finally.